# v-select/Vue: How to enter value not in the list?

Tags: vue.js, v-select

I'm trying to find a way to add a new value using v-select previously not in the list. So that the new value entered will become the selected option.

This is my current code:

```
        <v-select
          ref="systemSelect"
          v-model="reservation.system"
          name="system"
          label="Select System"
          :disabled="isBusy"
          :options="systems"
          @input="getSystems"
        />
```

In UI the component looks like this. Here I use Vuex only to get `:options`. Currently if I enter a new value and click outside that value disappears since its not found in the list

[image]

Expected: Would like to enter a new value and use this value as current in the form and save it. Is there a way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You're totally not using vuetify and I'm an idiot

Comment: no. My bad...should've mentioned I'm using v-select with bootstrap-vue

Comment: You're good, I'm just presumptuous. Sorry about that!

Comment: just curious is there a way to do this using vuetify? If so maybe i can use a similar approach in my code

Comment: are you using vue-select then? https://vue-select.org/

Comment: use v-combobox for adding new items.

Comment: @StevenSpungin This probably would've worked but as mentioned i'm using bootstrap-vue here. anyway thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 4):

If you're using vue select, you can use the attribute taggable and multiple to push your own options:

```
<v-select taggable multiple />
```

See this link:

https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#tagging

Comment: This does not work as using `multiple` creates a list instead of selecting a single value. Thanks for the suggestion tho

Comment: ended up using Bootstrap-vue's datalist component instead which allows this

Comment: FYI - you don't have to use `multiple` with `taggable` - I successfully set up a single-select that allowed unmatched user entries (also using the remote options w/ infinite scroll).